# How avoid Maven install add license tag to my pom?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project. Every time that I run a mvn install command, maven add a license tag like this in each pom:

```
   <license>
          <name>***</name>
          <url>***</url>
          <distribution>**</distribution>
          <comments>***</comments>
        </license>
```

In the pom is already present the right license and I do not want to add a new one.
It happens after that for another project I had to switch the mirror in my settings.xml.
Now I restored the orginal settings.xml and run again the mvn install, but this is still adding the new license tag.

Comment: Please show the project? Maven does not automatically add a license...

Answer (score 1):

Maven does not add license tags.

If a license tag is added, there must be a special Maven Plugin for that in the POM.